# How max numbers pthreads_rwlock I can to use in Linux 2.6

Tags: linux, multithreading, locking, pthreads

I have many shared data between threads in my server. If I use one pthread_rwlock, the multithreading stoppid. I use arrays of rwlocks:

```
#define DIR_LOCK_COUNT     32
pthread_rwlock_t dir_mutex[DIR_LOCK_COUNT];

... 
# into main thread initialize pthread_rwlock
for(i=0; i < DIR_LOCK_COUNT; i++){
    if(pthread_rwlock_init(&dir_mutex[i], NULL) != 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "can't initialize rwlock %i", i);
        return ERR;
    }
}

...
# in the worker thread 

int num = user_id % DIR_LOCK_COUNT;

pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&dir_mutex[num]);
struct dir *dir_trash = dict_search((dict*)user->dirs, &dir_trash_id);
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&dir_mutex[num]);
```

I have arrays of 35K users and 16 thread pool. Can I use dimension of pthread_rwlock is 1024 or more?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux / glibc NPTL implementation of `pthread_rwlock()` doesn't use any per-lock in-kernel resources.  If there's enough memory for the `pthread_rwlock_t` in the first place, then you can create the lock - `pthread_rwlock_init()` never fails in the NPTL implementation.